# Slack API - get values of other components from the same message when clicking a button

Tags: node.js, express, slack, slack-api

I have this interactive message:

```
 [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "The number of items you want to see (Top X)"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "static_select",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "X",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "1",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "The criteria you want to group by"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "static_select",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Select a criteria",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "criteria1",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "criteria1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Fetch P&L",
                    "emoji": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

[image: the message]

How can I get the values selected by the user in the 2 drop-down menus when she clicks on the button ?

It's not in the event payload I get from Slack. I am using the `NodeJS` libraries to communicate with Slack in an `express` app and would like a solution that uses those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Slack UI works a bit differently than a standard HTTP form.

Each interactive component (e.g. the select or button) is separate and when a user clicks on it, Slack will send a request containing only information about that component to your app.

To combine multiple interactive components you have two options:

- You can query in multiple steps. So you first send a message asking for the number of items. Then the user makes his choice and your app receives the request from Slack. Then your app replaces the message and asks for the criteria. and so on.
- Or you can use a [Slack Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs). That will be shown as modal window and allows you to query up to 5 elements in one step.

Comment: I Went the way of the dialog. Would you mind expanding a bit on the multiple steps method?

Comment: I added some more info on the multi-step approach. hope that clarifies things

Comment: If you have something lying around, could you please show how the multiple steps would work using pseudo-code (or proper-code). I'm not sure how to actually implement it (using which slack api, whihc functions etc)